# Issues in Shared Prfernces and Sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

My issue is Data is sucessfully inserted in to database but shared prefernces is not working when I  register and after that I  destroy the app they come from starting splashscreen. My intention is like facebook app when I am once login and after killing app again reopen it never ask login page it dispaly home page.I want like that.can any one tell how to combined shared prefernces with database?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

EditText et,et1,et2,et3,et4,et5;

TextView tv;
Button btn;
static MyDatabase mydb;
SQLiteDatabase db;
public static final String Filename = "logindata";
public static final String key = "status";
SharedPreferences sp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    sp = getSharedPreferences(Filename,MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean res = sp.getBoolean(key,false);
    if (res)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Result.class);
        startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sp created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "temp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    mydb = new MyDatabase(this);
    db = mydb.getWritableDatabase();
    ConnectivityManager connect = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo net = connect.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (net!=null&&net.isConnected())
    {
        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        btn.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
public void submitDetails(View v) {
   String user = et.getText().toString();
    String pwd = et1.getText().toString();
    String email = et2.getText().toString();
 String emailpatern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    if (user.equals("")) {
        et.setError("pls enter name");
    } else if (pwd.equals("")) {
        et1.setError("pls enter last name");
    } else if (email.equals("")) {
        et2.setError("Pls Enter Valid Email");
    } else if (!email.matches(emailpatern)) {
        et2.setError("Pls Enter Valid email charcters");
    }
    else if (user.equals())
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putBoolean(key, true);
        ed.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Result.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
        i.putExtra("k1", user);
        i.putExtra("k2", pwd);
        i.putExtra("k3", email);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    String qry = "insert into register values('"+user+"','"+pwd+"','"+email+"')";
    try
    {
     db.execSQL(qry);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("TAG:InsertionException",""+e);
    }
```

Mydatbase activity

```
       public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper
      {
Context c;
private static final String DBNAME = "anil";
private static final int VERSION = 1;
public MyDatabase(Context c)
{
    super(c,DBNAME,null,VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try
    {
        String qry = "create table register(User TEXT,Password TEXT,Email TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(qry);
        Toast.makeText(c,"created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("TAG: Table Creation",""+e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

logcat

05-03 02:11:08.611 27068-27068/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{anilkumar.com.iwtweb/anilkumar.com.iwtweb.Result}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at anilkumar.com.iwtweb.Result.onCreate(Result.java:28)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-03 02:11:12.162 78-111/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '41373368 anilkumar.com.iwtweb/anilkumar.com.iwtweb.SplashActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Result Activity

```
        public class Result extends AppCompatActivity


       {



TextView tv,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6;
String user,pwd,email;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);
     tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    user = b.getString("k1");
    pwd =b.getString("k2");
    email = b.getString("k3");
//here is error        tv.setText(user);
    tv2.setText(pwd);
    tv3.setText(email);

}
```

Comment: This `else if (user.equals(mydb))` is never true - so you actually never save the data into the SharedPreference. What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: Actually i dont know @ishmaelMalkitla can u give any solution for that

Comment: Is this a joke ? user is a String .mydb is a Database object. if (user.equals(mydb)) does not makes sense

Comment: Guys are right dude, you're literally comparing a String to a Database object. Remove that condition, just leave the else branch or make some other kind of check :P

Comment: then how to solve my issue any one explain

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the rest of your code works, please change your `submitDetails` method as follows:

```
public void submitDetails(View v) {
    String user = et.getText().toString();
    String pwd = et1.getText().toString();
    String email = et2.getText().toString();
    String emailpatern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    if (user.equals("")) {
        et.setError("pls enter name");
    } else if (pwd.equals("")) {
        et1.setError("pls enter last name");
    } else if (email.equals("")) {
        et2.setError("Pls Enter Valid Email");
    } else if (!email.matches(emailpatern)) {
        et2.setError("Pls Enter Valid email charcters");
    }
    else
    {   
       //at this point you can try and insert the submitted values into the db
       String qry = "insert into register values('"+user+"','"+pwd+"','"+email+"')";
    try
    {
        db.execSQL(qry);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //the insert was successful - here you simply "cache" the details
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putBoolean(key, true);
        ed.commit();       
        //then you continue to load the next Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
        i.putExtra("k1", user);
        i.putExtra("k2", pwd);
        i.putExtra("k3", email);

        startActivity(i);

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("TAG:InsertionException",""+e);
        //there were some problems
    }

    }    
}
```

Please try with these changes and let us know if your problem is solved.

Comment: Error occured.unfortunately stopped when i m killing app and again press it shows that error @ishamelmakitila

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace so we can examine the error.

Comment: see above for logact @ishmael

Comment: Please add the code for Result activity - that's where you have a problem. Perhaps after fixing the problem you might get something going. Please paste the code so we can examine it.

Comment: check once reult activity also aadded @ishmael

Comment: You are calling `Bundle b = i.getExtras();` which you did not set (this causes `NullPointerException` when you try to lookup using this bundle) - in stead you have set the String-Extras directly. Therefore you need to retrieve these using `user = i.getStringExtra("k1");`
    `pwd =i.getStringExtra("k2");`
    `email = i.getStringExtra("k3");`

Comment: sharedprefrence is created it shows result also but i m destroy the app it starts from again registration form @ishmael

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110881/discussion-between-ishmaelmakitla-and-anilkumarjohn).